# Python statement understanding to split something from a string

Tags: python, split, strip

I have the following string:

```
SG_ LRE_Element_Buffer_1 : 180|28@1+ (1,0) [0|0] "NA"  RVU
```

What is needed is to extract the "28" from it.

The following line is supposed to do that, but it produces error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
length = int(line.strip().split()[3].split('|')[1].split('@')[0])
```

Can anyone explain what that line does why this error pops up?

Comment: It works fine. It does give 28 for me. Please post complete code

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
the_string = 'SG_ LRE_Element_Buffer_1 : 180|28@1+ (1,0) [0|0] "NA" RVU'
print(the_string[the_string.find('|')+1:the_string.find('@')])
```

output

```
28
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: `line.split()[3].split('|')[1].split('@')[0]`

[image]